# Is there a way to add texture to a Metaball following a curve guide?

Tags: texturing

I have a Metaball following a curve guide dropping out of a bucket. I originally had UV Spheres as the collection following the curve guide, but the pattern was too ball-like.

As you can see below the UV Sphere's easily have the texture applied that I want.

Is there a way to add textures to a Metaball?

[image: metaball and uv sphere]

Comment: If you don't need UVs, yes: just do it : )

Comment: Won't I need UVs to adjust the scale of the texture?

Comment: You should add more information about the textures you want to use.

Comment: I want to use a Texture I found online and apply the Normal through the Normal Map. And possibly use the Albeto too. Whenever I try this, nothing happens to the Metaball unless I convert to mesh, but then it looses its functions.